# How to exit fullscreen on pressing ESC or by toggling the fullscreen button

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

In the below snippet, when "Make a fullscreen" button is pressed, the iFrame enters fullscreen mode. I'm looking for a solution to exit fullscreen mode on pressing "ESC" or by pressing "Make fullscreen button" again.

```
<button onclick="makeFullscreen('game');">[Make a fullscreen]</button>
```

```
function makeFullscreen(id){
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.style = "position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"
}
```

Fully working

```
const fullscreenStyle = "position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:99999;"

const normalStyle = "width:1000px;height:700px;border:0;"

function enterFullScreen(el) {
  el.style = fullscreenStyle;
  document.querySelector('.button1').style = 'position:absolute;top:0;right:0;z-index:999999;';
}

function exitFullScreen(el) {
  el.style = normalStyle;
  document.querySelector('.button1').style = 'position:absolute;top:auto;right:auto;';
}


function toggleFullScreen() {
  var el = document.getElementById("game");
  if (el.style.position === "fixed") {
    exitFullScreen(el);
  } else {
    enterFullScreen(el);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.key === "Escape") {
    var el = document.getElementById("game");
    exitFullScreen(el);
  }  
}, false);
```

Comment: What solutions have you tried? Add them to the post as well. And since you are using JS, why not use the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) ?

Comment: Style solution works perfectly on phones.

Answer (score 1):

Since [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) is out, another solution can be that instead of binding `Make a Fullscreen` logic to the button, bind the logic for toggling full screen. For that :

1. Store fullscreen and normal mode CSS in 2 separate variables
2. Create 2 functions, `enterFullscreen` and `exitFullScreen`
3. Create a 3rd function `toggleFullScreen` that checks the mode and does the following :

- If fullscreen mode is ON, call `exitFullscreen`
- Else call `enterFullScreen`

**To implement exit on pressing ESC**

1. Add an event listener for [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) events
2. When the event is triggered, check the [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) in the event.
3. If the `key` matches `Escape`, call `exitFullScreen`

The following solution does the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <iframe id="game" style="width:1000px;height:700px;border:0;" allowfullscreen="true" msallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock allow-orientation-lock allow-popups" src="https://randomurl.com/">
  </iframe>
  <button onclick="toggleFullScreen('game');">
     [Toggle fullscreen] 
  </button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 const fullscreenStyle = "position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"
 const normalStyle = "width:1000px;height:700px;border:0;"

 function enterFullScreen(el) {
    el.style = fullscreenStyle;
 }

 function exitFullScreen(el) {
    el.style = normalStyle;
 }

 function toggleFullScreen() {
   var el = document.getElementById("game");
   if (el.style.position === "fixed") {
     exitFullScreen(el);
   } else {
     enterFullScreen(el);
   }
 }

 document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
   if (e.key === "Escape") {
     var el = document.getElementById("game");
     exitFullScreen(el);
   }  
 }, false);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. There is still one issue that i figured out today. It doesnt want to exit fullscreen once you start playing game. For example you can toggle fullscreen and instantly clikc "esc" and it works as expected. But once you click on iframe in fullscreen or start playing game "esc" doesnt doesnt work. Been playing with `position` but no luck so far. Why is that? Otherwise code is exactly what i was trying to make. 

Also tried to trigger `esc` button with `keyCode: 27` but it didnt help.

Comment: Generally, the root cause for such issues is that the keyboard event does not get propagated to the component that is listening for it. Check for any [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) or [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) statements that might be doing this.

Comment: Actually i realised that button is way better option than `esc`. The only last think i cannot figure out is how to put `quit fullscreen` button while we at `fullscreen`.  Lets say we put iframe and button under `div class="games"`. Making `games` class `relative` and button class `position: absolute; top:0; right:0;`. At small screen `button` appears at right place and stays at same level after  triggering `fullscreen`. I mean at fullscreen it does't appear in top / right / left corner but stays at `smallscreen` top / right / left screen level.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8qpwvo7y/1/

Comment: Working version in first post, thanks for everything.